# Update matplotlib Pie in realtime

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

This is my loop to detect and show gender and age. I am trying to plot this on matplotlib pie chart but everytime it runs the loop it opens up a different chart for every predictions. How do I update the same chart in realtime.

Here I am updating the complete code

The complete code for detecting age and gender of a person using Python and OpenCV.

```

```
import os
import cv2
import dlib
import numpy as np
import argparse
import inception_resnet_v1
import tensorflow as tf
from imutils.face_utils import FaceAligner
from imutils.face_utils import rect_to_bb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This script detects faces from web cam input, "
                                                 "and estimates age and gender for the detected faces.",
                                     formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("--weight_file", type=str, default=None,
                        help="path to weight file (e.g. weights.18-4.06.hdf5)")
    parser.add_argument("--depth", type=int, default=16,
                        help="depth of network")
    parser.add_argument("--width", type=int, default=8,
                        help="width of network")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


def draw_label(image, point, label, font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
               font_scale=1, thickness=2):
    size = cv2.getTextSize(label, font, font_scale, thickness)[0]
    x, y = point
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y - size[1]), (x + size[0], y), (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
    cv2.putText(image, label, point, font, font_scale, (255, 255, 255), thickness)


def main(sess,age,gender,train_mode,images_pl):
    args = get_args()
    depth = args.depth
    k = args.width

    # for face detection
    detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")
    fa = FaceAligner(predictor, desiredFaceWidth=160)

    # load model and weights
    img_size = 160

    # cap video
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

    while True:
        # get video frame
        ret, img = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            print("error: failed to capture image")
            return -1

        input_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img_h, img_w, _ = np.shape(input_img)


        detected = detector(input_img, 1)
        faces = np.empty((len(detected), img_size, img_size, 3))

        for i, d in enumerate(detected):
            x1, y1, x2, y2, w, h = d.left(), d.top(), d.right() + 1, d.bottom() + 1, d.width(), d.height()
            xw1 = max(int(x1 - 0.4 * w), 0)
            yw1 = max(int(y1 - 0.4 * h), 0)
            xw2 = min(int(x2 + 0.4 * w), img_w - 1)
            yw2 = min(int(y2 + 0.4 * h), img_h - 1)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            # cv2.rectangle(img, (xw1, yw1), (xw2, yw2), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            faces[i, :, :, :] = fa.align(input_img, gray, detected[i])
            # faces[i,:,:,:] = cv2.resize(img[yw1:yw2 + 1, xw1:xw2 + 1, :], (img_size, img_size))

        if len(detected) > 0:
            # predict ages and genders of the detected faces
            ages,genders = sess.run([age, gender], feed_dict={images_pl: faces, train_mode: False})

        # draw results
        for i, d in enumerate(detected):
            label = "{}, {}".format(int(ages[i]), "F" if genders[i] == 0 else "M")
            draw_label(img, (d.left(), d.top()), label)
            #for i in range(20):

                #label = 'M', 'F'
            sizes = [15, 30]
            explode = (0, 0.1)
            fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
            ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=label, autopct='%1.1f%%',
                    shadow=True, startangle=90)
            ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio 
        plt.show()
            #break


        cv2.imshow("result", img)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)

        if key == 27:
            break

def load_network(model_path):
    sess = tf.Session()
    images_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 160, 160, 3], name='input_image')
    images_norm = tf.map_fn(lambda frame: tf.image.per_image_standardization(frame), images_pl)
    train_mode = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
    age_logits, gender_logits, _ = inception_resnet_v1.inference(images_norm, keep_probability=0.8,
                                                                 phase_train=train_mode,
                                                                 weight_decay=1e-5)
    gender = tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(gender_logits), 1)
    age_ = tf.cast(tf.constant([i for i in range(0, 101)]), tf.float32)
    age = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(tf.nn.softmax(age_logits), age_), axis=1)
    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                       tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(init_op)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_path)
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        print("restore model!")
    else:
        pass
    return sess,age,gender,train_mode,images_pl
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--model_path", "--M", default="./models", type=str, help="Model Path")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    sess, age, gender, train_mode,images_pl = load_network(args.model_path)
    main(sess,age,gender,train_mode,images_pl)
```

```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code that you provide right now is not runnable and as the answer below does not solve your problem, there is more happening in your script than we can see.

Comment: Updated the question with  full code.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should post your full script, I doubt that it is runnable for anybody else but you, because we don't have the input. Instead, please spend some time reducing your code to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which isolates your problem, so that we can provide a solution to that particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Move `fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()` before the for loop starts

Comment: The issue is still there, however I removed the for xx (1000) loop as it goes out of bound beyond 20 plots, so put it above the first for loop ,but it did not happen as expected.

Comment: Then the data you're feeding it might not be identical for each run of your script.Try and pickle it on the first run.Check on a second run if the data is the same with the pickle

Comment: As these are the predictions of age and gender the data changes quite often. Each image it plots correctly but when it goes realtime the plots just don't show the updated results.

Comment: So you want to plot in real-time the pie chart ? Real time as in it will modify itself at each loop

Comment: Yes , modify the chart everytime the data changes, I have also updated the code in my question with the full version.

Comment: Oh, in that case you are plotting a normal graph.You need to use matplotlib.animation for live graphs. He're a tutorial on live graphs : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmYPzESC5YY